# чем отличаются jsonText ->> path от json_extract в mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, json

Можно распарсить json двумя способами:

`set @var = jsonText ->> '$. ...'`

`set @var = json_extract(jsonText, '$. ...')`

Только в чем разница?

Comment: А доку читали? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html "the -> operator serves as an alias for the JSON_EXTRACT()", "column->>path is an improved, unquoting extraction operator. Whereas the -> operator simply extracts a value, the ->> operator in addition unquotes the extracted result."  У mysql хорошая дока, пользуйтесь.

Comment: не то меня интересует. С тем же успехом я могу сравнить просто jsonText -> '$.path' - и тогда он ничем не будет отличаться? и там и там с двойными кавычками. Суть в методе - отличаются ли они

Comment: `->` -- синоним `json_extract` с двумя аргументами. Это значит что разница только в написании (обратите однако внимание, что json_extract поддерживает и больше аргументов). А вот ->> отличается тем, что извлекает не json а непосредственно значение (грубо говоря без кавычек).